# Best way to make a large "X" over an element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of items of varying heights. If the item is no longer available, I want there to be a large 'X' over its entire container. Here's what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/dm3103d9/3/

There is clearly something wrong with the way I'm doing the rotation. I'm using inverse tangent since I know the opposite (height) and adjacent (width).

HTML

```
<div class="small square">
    <div class="one x-line"></div>
    <div class="two x-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="medium square">
    <div class="one x-line"></div>
    <div class="two x-line"></div>
</div>
<div class="big square">
   <div class="one x-line"></div>
   <div class="two x-line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.square {
   position: relative;
   width: 150px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   border: 2px solid green;
   display: inline-block;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.small.square {
    height: 100px;
}
.medium.square {
    height: 200px;
}
.big.square {
    height: 300px;
}
.x-line {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
   width: 12px;
   height: 100%;
   margin-left: -6px;
   background: #EA323D;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.square').each(function (index, obj) {
    // get container dimensions
    var square_width = $(obj).width();
    var square_height = $(obj).height();

    // get the diagonal width
    var line_height = Math.sqrt((square_width * square_width) + (square_height * square_height));

    // used inverse tangent to get degrees
    var rotation = 57.29577 * Math.atan(square_height/square_width);

    var line_one = $(obj).find('.x-line.one');
    var line_two = $(obj).find('.x-line.two');
    $(line_one).css({
        height: line_height,
       transform: 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)'
    });
    $(line_two).css({
        height: line_height,
        transform: 'rotate(' + (-1 * rotation) + 'deg)'
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds really bad, but this seems like TOTALLY bad practise/bad way of doing this.

Comment: The title of the question makes it primarily opinion-based (asking for best way). The content of the question is something completely different and does not contain the actual code, does not describe clearly the goal, and does not say how the code fails to achieve that.

Comment: @Nubby, the atan gives you radians, you are setting degrees.

Comment: @MrCoder Do you have any alternate suggestions, or is that all?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I don't understand, the code is in the JSFiddle and the question represents the content.

Comment: All relevant code should be in the question. JSFiddle is nice and helpful, but it is extra.

Comment: My alternative would be to have a overlayed translucent image, and just set the width/height to the control's size

Comment: @GolezTrol well there was a lot including all the css, html, jquery so I opted for JSFiddle. And it seems like something that would work best with a visual.

Comment: @Nubby, the point is, yes, by all means include the JSFiddle, but put the code into the question too. Links breaks, some people are using mobile devices to answer questions and JSfiddle is not as great on mobile. Also, people will likely get to this answer on Google later and JSFiddle may have gone away then your question won't be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to remember is that `Math.atan()` and friends return values in radians, not degrees. Fortunately, `rotate()` can take radians:

```
$(line_one).css({
    height: line_height,
    top: (square_height - line_height) /2,
    transform: 'rotate(' + rotation + 'rad)'
});
$(line_two).css({
    height: line_height,
    top: (square_height - line_height) / 2,
    transform: 'rotate(' + (-1 * rotation) + 'rad)'
});
```

I've also added a `top` override, as you'll notice that without it, your X will sit a bit lower than you might otherwise want it.

Of additional note is that square_height and square_width should be reversed, since your bars start vertical instead of horizontal:

```
var rotation = Math.atan(square_width/square_height);
```

I'll make no comment on whether or not this is the *best* way, as that is largely subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a CSS only solution. This is my quick attempt:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="small square out-of-stock"></div>
<div class="medium square out-of-stock"></div>
<div class="big square out-of-stock"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.out-of-stock:before, .out-of-stock:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 12px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(25deg);
    transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.out-of-stock:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(155deg);
    transform: rotate(155deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dm3103d9/8/

You can then target different classes and make adjustments to the rotation of the lines, colours, etc.

An even easier way would be having the mask as @Hotted24 suggested, then you can use `backgroud-size: 100%` to scale the cross. Good luck!

Comment: This looks good, but there would be any set heights. I'll try using a masking element instead as you all suggested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The CSS cross will stretch, as the height is set to 100% of the parent div's height.

Comment: +1 for a CSS solution. You could use an image data-uri instead: http://jsfiddle.net/we47c482/

Answer (score 0):

Rotate take values in degrees :

```
var rotation = 57.29577*Math.atan(square_width/square_height);
```

**NB :** 57.29577 = 360 / ( 2*PI )

BTW, using a mask ( basically a cross in your case ) with a transparent background as an  element, you would be able to just set width and height to get a nice way to fit it well =)

Comment: `square_height/square_width` should be `square_width/square_height`.  http://jsfiddle.net/dm3103d9/1/

Comment: @GolezTrol you're right, I just precised the radians/degrees translation =) Editing =)

Comment: And kudos for that. I was just curious and tried your solution in the Fiddle that OP supplied. It's not the only issue left, though, and your suggestion of using a mask is probably better.

Comment: @Hotted24 The want the lines to go from one corner to another.

Comment: @Nubby That's another issue (or another part of the issue). This answer at least explains why the lines where messed up altogether, which seemed to be the essense of your question. The size of the cross is right now, the only thing left is to calculate the right top.

Comment: @GolezTrol Alright. I'll make sure to express the exact reasons I need help next time.